# Perl - A Regex for a very special String

Tags: regex, perl

refering to my nftables Gtk project i have another very special problem.
i need to split up the following string in the marked parts.

real input:

```
ip daddr foo.com tcp flags == ack counter limit rate 5/second accept
```

should split up in these parts:

```
['ip', 'daddr', 'foo.com'] ['tcp' 'flags', '== ack'] ['counter limit rate 5/second accept']
```

something other can be:

```
tcp flags & (ack, syn, fin) == (ack, syn) drop
```

should split up in

```
 ['tcp', 'flags', '& (ack | syn | fin) == (ack | syn)'] ['drop']
```

the trick is, that i need the 1st, the 2nd and 3rd one of each little part as an array, the last thing counter etc as a normal string.

i created these Regexes to do this.

```
if ($inrule =~ /^\s*([a-z]+\s+[a-z]+\s+[=!<>]{0,2}\s+([A-Za-z0-9._-]+|\{[A-Za-z0-9._\s-]+\\})\s+)+[A-Za-z0-9._\/\s-]+$/ )
       {
        my ($actions) = $inrule =~ /\s*(((log\s(prefix\s\"[0-9A-Za-z]\")?)|
                                   (counter)|
                                   (set\s[0-9A-Za-z.-_])|
                                   (limit\srate\s[1-9]{1}[0-9]*\/(second|minute|hour|day|week){1}))\s*)*
                                   \s*(drop|return|reject|accept)?$/gx;

        my @rulecontent = ( $inrule =~ /([a-z]+\s+[a-z]+\s+[=!<>]{0,2}\s+([A-Za-z0-9._-]+|\{[A-Za-z0-9._\s-]+\\})/g );
        print @rulecontent;
        print $actions;

       }
```

The question is: @rulecontent contains the correct input, $actions contains nothing. How i can fix this?
I hope you can help me, because i have no idea to continue.. thank you very much.

Comment: It's hard to understand what you mean. Please could you post some real data, showing as much variation in the data as possible? In particular it is impossible to verify the first regex when you have just `statement` in that line. Why can't you just split on pipe characters `|`, like this `split /\s*\|\s*/, $line`

Comment: What is your question? Don't those regexes work for you?

Comment: I think what he wants is `[ [ 'ip', 'dadds', 'foo.com' ], ['tcp', 'flags', 'ack' ], [ 'count', 'limit rate 5/second', 'accept' ] ]` though that is total speculation.

Comment: you get it! i want ['ip', 'daddr', 'foo.com'] ['tcp', 'flags', '== ack'] and [ 'count', 'limit rate 5/second', 'accept' ] i think its very hard to explain ;)

Comment: Is this table generated by an `nftables` command? If so which one? It is impossible to write an adequate regex without knowing *exactly* the range of strings it is required to match.

Comment: this is only a rule of nftables. you can create it with: 'nft add rule ip table chain ip daddr foo.com tcp flags == ack count limit rate 5/second accept' i found a BISON file in ftables sources. maybe i can use this? https://github.com/aborrero/pkg-nftables/blob/master/src/parser.y

Comment: Suggesting you to write a parser with [Pegex](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Pegex/lib/Pegex.pod) but, maybe here is a simpler solution...

Comment: okay, i will have a look at this. thnak you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay, i've got another idea to solve my problem: what do you think about this:
1st check and substring all actions from the string.
2nd run the statement-regex.

i will test it later and give you a response if this work.